# Make one color of color ramp emissive

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, emission

I have this cube with a displacement modifier and a color ramp and I'm trying to set the purple part to be emissive.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

File:[image]

Comment: At the moment, the color-ramp has no input, so your whole object is one color (0.5 on the ramp). The ramp is having no effect. Which parts do you want to be purple, which parts black?

Comment: I want most of it black(displaced parts) and the parts closer to the center to be purple

Comment: To give the effect as if the black part is a shell and the purple glow is appearing through cracks in the shell.

Comment: Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: I'm using Evee Engine

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaDkMP5ruh4&pp=wgIGCgQQAhgB

Comment: I will do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, but you can use *Ambient Occlusion* to drive the ColorRamp with the emission:

[image: Emit]

Comment: I'll try it, thanks

Comment: I used this method and it worked perfectly but when I tried adding a plane below the cube the whole bottom started to glow due to shadows between cube and plane.

Comment: That's why I said it's not ideal - if you want better control over the "position" of the emission (without it changing based on interactions like ambient occlusion), you will need to use the same texture for the displacement as you do for the shading - Unfortunately, blender's shader system has no access to the textures used by the displacement modifier,  therefore you will either have to perform the displacement via shader (which requires cycles and a highly subdivided model), or you can import an external "noise" texture and use it for both.

Comment: Last option is to bake the emission texture when the object is "on its own", and then apply that texture when you need a plane nearby or something like that.

Comment: Can you please explain further the option with the noise texture? Even better if you add a screenshot.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it's been a while since I properly applied a non-procedural texture to a cube (to a plane it's easy because there a re no "sides" to worry about). I'll look into making an example if I can,

Comment: That would be great, thanks.